# Hadoop MapReduce: Two Keys in one line, but how?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, aggregate, aggregation

I have csv files containing records separated by semicolon. Each line is one record. Each line contains edge information of a graph. This means one line looks like the following:

> Node_X;Node_Y;5

it is interpreted as an edge or link between nodes x and y having the weight of 5. My mappers get this input. Now what I want to achieve is to aggregate the information using the nodes.

The following example illustrates my scenario:

> Node_X;Node_Y;5
>
> Node_X;Node_Z;10
>
> Node_X;Node_A;60
>
> Node_Y;Node_A;20

Then the result by nodes should be:

> Node_X;75; Node_Y;25; Node_A;80

I want to collect all distinct nodes and give them as weight the sum of the weights they have with other nodes.

In my mapper, I can read the edge information:

> Node_X;Node_A;60

But how can I make two keys out of this line for my reducers?
It should be something like

```
context.write(Node_X,60);

context.write(Node_A,60);
```

How can I achieve this?

Thx!

P.S.: The edges are undirected.

Comment: What have you tried? `context.write(Node_X,60); context.write(Node_A,60);` should work

Comment: Is it possible to write twice in one map section? I though it would override the previous one. If it works like this, it is like a big charm for me. will try out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It should be something like
>
> context.write(Node_X,60);
>
> context.write(Node_A,60);

Assuming you haven't tried it before asking, that will work.

Comment: Tried it, it works as you told. I was directly kind of thinking that it would override the first write operation. I am newbie, learned something new. In my case, getting stats for edges and nodes is just few lines of codes changes. Hadoop MR is really amazing.